# How should socket.io handhake look like via Postman?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, jmeter, postman, jmeter-plugins

I have simple Socket.IO server (code below):

```
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';


const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);
const port = 3000;

app.get('/help', (req, res) => {
  res.send('HELP PAGE')
})

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id);
  console.log('User connected');

  socket.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log('Message: ' + msg);
    io.emit('message', msg + socket.id);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('User disconnected');
  });
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server Socket.IO listen on: ${port}`);
});
```

Now I am trying to test it via Jmeter. To do it, I should discover how to make handshake firstly. I am trying to send request on:

```
http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket
```

(Due to R&D I am sending request via Postman. It will let me later to copy this request to JMeter)
but response i get is

```
{
    "code": 2,
    "message": "Bad handshake method"
}
```

What should I do?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're sending the same request in JMeter as you do in Postman. Pay attention not only to URL and Body but consider also comparing [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers).

As per https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2717 you might need to add [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header with the value of `*/*`. It cane be done via [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager)

In general if the request works in Postman and doesn't work in JMeter the easiest way for converting the request is just recording it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html). If you configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy you will be able to replay your request or collection and JMeter will capture the requests.

Comment: Doesn't work in Postman nor Jmeter ;)